Unable to Create a Python Wheel to Use with Databricks from Visual Studio Code
I am trying to create a Python wheel to be used with Databricks. I'm using VS Code to generate the wheel.
I have the following setup.py file:
import setuptools

with open("QuickStart.MD", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="newlib", 
    version="0.1.8",
    author="name",
    author_email="newmail@gmail.com",
    description="framework",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
   'pyodbc',
   'jsonschema'
]
)

My README.md files looks something like the following:
# Example Package
This is a simple example package. You can use
[Github-flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)
to write your content 

When I run python setup.py bdist_wheel
I get the error:
invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

You are missing wheel package.
pip install wheel

If you already got this, maybe the default python is something else. try python -v and understand what is the version. Try with
pip3 install wheel


Thanks pip install wheel did the trick
